# Always display leaders, even when I have a line break

Tags: plain-tex, leaders

Consider this code:

```
\def\leaderfill{\leaders\hbox to 1mm{\hss.\hss}\hfill}
\vbox{\noindent\hsize 3.4cm Alpha adslf adsf kalsdf\leaderfill 1123}

\bye
```

The output is

[image: no leader shown]

But I'd like to have dots before the 1123, similar to this

```
\def\leaderfill{\leaders\hbox to 1mm{\hss.\hss}\hfill}
\vbox{\noindent\hsize 3.4cm Alpha adslf adsf kalsdf \strut\leaderfill 1123}

\bye
```

(see the `\strut` before the `\leaderfill`)
[image]

Is there a way to do this automatically without the »space / strut« before the leader? What would be the recommended way to get what I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leaders are like glue, and dropped at a break, so you just need to make sure that it never breaks there (`\nobreak`) and isn't dropped (`\hbox{}`) and that there is somewhere else where the line break can happen (`\penalty0`)

```
\def\leaderfill{\leaders\hbox to 1mm{\hss.\hss}\hfill}
\vbox{\noindent\hsize 3.4cm 
      Alpha adslf adsf kalsdf\penalty0\hbox{}\nobreak\leaderfill 1123}

\bye
```

Comment: Thank you very much, David. I can't see any bad side effects, so I'll add it to my code.

Comment: of course if the first line were actually multiple lines, the element on the last line doesn't fit on the last text line, and it is desired to have the leaders also on the last text line, this isn't sufficient.  knuth covered a similar (but somewhat more complicated) situation in an example on p.393 of the *texbook*.  (it's basically the same as setting the author of an epigraph flush right on a new line, but with dots instead of spaces.)

Comment: Thank you @barbarabeeton for the pointer. One day I should get a copy of the TeXbook... wait, I _own_ a copy. One day I should read my copy of the TeXbook.